# DataGridView databinding. How handle row changing?

Tags: .net, data-binding

I am using DataBinding to bind List with my gridview.
To color rows according to Node state i subscribe to gridview.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged to handle changing of  Node state.

GridView displays changes, but CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged not raises.

Can somebody propose me another way to handle cell changes in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx).